# Relative file paths in python

Tags: python

I've been working on a python application that takes input from the user.

The input is the path to a text file.

Once the user has entered the path to a text file, it will be opened, and the contents displayed in the console.

```
file = input()

with open(file, "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
```

Currently, it will only accept 'literal file paths', for example `C:/users/name/documents/filename.txt`

I would like it to accept relative file paths aswell, for example `./file.txt`, which should get a file named `file.txt` in the current directory, or `../file2.txt` which should go up a directory (`..`) and then get a file called `file2.txt`.

How can I achieve this?

I was unable to find any relevant answers.

Comment: . and .. are relevant to your current working directory. So make sure they are correct. (open command doesn't care about absolute paths and relative paths)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, it already supports relative file paths as-is. What makes you think that it doesn't? Are you sure the current working directory is set to what you think it is?